# How to Create a generic method with 1 known property. Want to dynamic get the properties in different class with Generic Class property

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I want to practice code with DRY principle, but my method uses 2 different classes, classOneDTO and classTwoDTO.. They have different properties and I want to linked it with PRIMARYIDENTIFIER prop with both have the same..

How can I create a generic method  to get the property that I want to query with Linq.

Updated: my purpose is to have a generic method that will query the PrimaryIdentifier and get the data to it whether they are using classOneDTO or classTwoDTO. Is there a way to have a single generic method to do this?

```
 private void genericMethod<T>(List<T> workList, GridView grid, int columnNo)
        {
            if (workList.Any())
            {
                string CodeString = default;


                // Want to dynamic get the properties in different class with PrimaryIDentifier property
                // want to check if PrimaryIdentifier is NULL OR EMPTY
                var getDataOne = workList.Cast<classOneDTO>().FirstOrDefault(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.PrimaryIdentifier));
                // causing error because of the CAST if wrong type request
                var getDataTwo = workList.Cast<classTwoDTO>().FirstOrDefault(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.PrimaryIdentifier));
                if (getDataOne != null || getDataTwo != null)
                {
                    CodeString = (getDataOne != null) ? getDataOne.PrimaryIdentifier : getDataTwo.PrimaryIdentifier;
                }

               
            }
            
        }

 public class classOneDTO
    {
        public int PatientID { get; set; }
        public string PrimaryIdentifier { get; set; }
        public string FirstName{ get; set; }
         // so oonnn...
    }
 public class classTwoDTO
    {
        public int EntryID { get; set; }
        public string PrimaryIdentifier { get; set; }
        public string Location{ get; set; }
        // so oonnn...
    }
```

Comment: i dont get what the method you want to make is supposed to do

Comment: I updated my description. kindly check @Hervé

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that you need is to make both your classes implement the same interface, i.e. `IDTO`:

```cs
public interface IDTO
{
    string PrimaryIdentifier { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can tell the compiler to accept only types that implement your new interface:

```cs
private void GenericMethod<DTO>(List<DTO> workList, GridView grid, int columnNo)
    where DTO: IDTO
{
    if (workList.Any())
    {
        string CodeString = default;

        var getData = workList.FirstOrDefault(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.PrimaryIdentifier));
        if (getData != null)
        {
            CodeString = getData?.PrimaryIdentifier;
        }
    }
}
```

*(Pay attention to the 2nd row)*
Additionally, I also made minor adjustments to your class and method namings based on standard [.Net naming convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions).

Here's the full code:

```cs
    public class Client
    {
        private void GenericMethod<DTO>(List<DTO> workList, GridView grid, int columnNo)
            where DTO: IDTO
        {
            if (workList.Any())
            {
                string CodeString = default;

                var getData = workList.FirstOrDefault(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.PrimaryIdentifier));
                if (getData != null)
                {
                    CodeString = getData?.PrimaryIdentifier;
                }


            }

        }
    }

    public class ClassOneDTO : IDTO
    {
        public int PatientID { get; set; }
        public string PrimaryIdentifier { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        // so oonnn...
    }
    public class ClassTwoDTO : IDTO
    {
        public int EntryID { get; set; }
        public string PrimaryIdentifier { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        // so oonnn...
    }

    public interface IDTO
    {
        string PrimaryIdentifier { get; set; }
    }
```

---

EDIT: as **Johnathan Barclay** correctly pointed out, there's actually no need to have a generic method if you don't need some more advanced logic there that you didn't show in your example.

```cs
private void GenericMethod(IEnumerable<IDTO> workList, GridView grid, int columnNo)
{
    if (workList.Any())
    {
        string CodeString = default;

        var getData = workList.FirstOrDefault(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.PrimaryIdentifier));
        if (getData != null)
        {
            CodeString = getData?.PrimaryIdentifier;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If the answer solved your question, please accept it by clicking the tick mark beside it as it will show people that this solution worked for your problem

Comment: cheers mate let me try it now. @Andrii

Comment: There's no need to use generics here. Just have the method take an `IEnumerable<IDTO>` parameter.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay can you please elaborate?

Comment: If you change the signature to `void GenericMethod(IEnumerble<IDTO> workList, GridView grid, int columnNo)` it will behave identically.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay good point, agree. Add it into the answer as well. My only point is that maybe there's some kind of logic the author didn't add to the example, yet it requires to use a generic method

Comment: I dont think so because the workList can be the ClassOneDTO or classTwo.. I already tried it on my code and it has error 'Cannot convert ClassoneDTO to IDTO' @JohnathanBarclay

Comment: @JiriumJ make sure you change your class to implement interface: `public class ClassOneDTO : IDTO`

Comment: I added a new method implementation to the answer. You can copy the full code, and then replace method with new implementation (below EDIT mark), and you will see how it works